# Is an assumption wrong for my variable or is this sum of two `arg`s, not cancelling each other to 0 due to a bug?

Tags: sympy

Is an assumption wrong for `Tl` or is this sum of two `arg`s, not cancelling each other to `0` due to missing implementation?

Theoretically the negation of the integral part should be pulled before the `arg`, which leads the args to cancel each other.

```python
>>> from sympy import I, arg, Symbol
>>> Tl = Symbol('Tl', real=True, zero=False, nonzero=True, positive=True, finite=True, infinite=False)
>>> Tl.assumptions0
{'real': True,
 'extended_real': True,
 'complex': True,
 'infinite': False,
 'imaginary': False,
 'finite': True,
 'hermitian': True,
 'commutative': True,
 'zero': False,
 'nonzero': True,
 'extended_nonzero': True,
 'positive': True,
 'extended_positive': True,
 'extended_nonpositive': False,
 'negative': False,
 'nonnegative': True,
 'extended_nonnegative': True,
 'extended_negative': False,
 'nonpositive': False
}
>>> (arg(Tl+I)+arg(Tl-I)).simplify()
arg(Tl - I) + arg(Tl + I)
>>> (arg(Tl+I)+arg(Tl-I)).subs(Tl, -2)
0
>>> (arg(Tl+I)+arg(Tl-I)).subs(Tl, -1)
0
>>> (arg(Tl+I)+arg(Tl-I)).subs(Tl, 0)
0
>>> (arg(Tl+I)+arg(Tl-I)).subs(Tl, 1)
0
>>> (arg(Tl+I)+arg(Tl-I)).subs(Tl, 2)
0
```

Comment: I'm not an expert in `sympy`, but my impression is that `simplify` uses a variety of heuristics or 'strategies'.  Read the docs.  It may not have a strategy that applies to `arg`.  It does not claim to handle all theoretically possible cases.

Comment: @hpaulj Right. This why I had the question, whether I miss something, or it is just not implemented or a bug.
In the latter case I would open an issue, but I saw that people did not consider corner cases and the result was basically correct, but people missed e.g. an assumption.

Comment: This just isn't something that `simplify` has any handler for. You can manually simplify this with e.g. `(arg(Tl+I)+arg(Tl-I)).rewrite(arg, atan2)`.